# Why is this razor syntax giving me an error?

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, syntax-error

I have the following code

http://bc.coverstar.com/images/error.gif

Why am I getting a syntax error after my Razor comment??

Comment: The braces are probably sending razor parser for a loop. Out of curiosity, does breaking that jQuery code into multiple lines have any relevance?

Comment: I added line breaks the editdata, putting everything on it's own line.  No change.

Comment: The image you used on this question is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way is to write

```
@{Model.DefinitionID}
```

or

```
@Model.DefinitionID
```

**UPD**:
In order to use Razor syntax within JavaScript, code should be wrapped within `<text>` tag. E.g.:

```
 <text>@Model.DefinitionID</text>
```

Note: `text` tag won't be seen in output.

Comment: Doing this seems to fix the problem: editData: { definitionID: function () { return @(Model.DefinitionID); } }.  Although not exactly what I want to do every time I need to use model data in a json object.